# Why use loop instead block in macros in C

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)

Hello, in many C macros programmers use special one-loop, for example:

```
#define do_something(a) do { execute(a); count(a); } while(0)
```

because of when you want to do this macro in loop and you don't use "{}".
Why they aren't using simple block instead? I mean, doesn't

```
#define do_something(a) { execute(a); count(a); }
```

have the very same effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
if( something ) do_something(a);
else something_else();
```

expands to:

```
if( something ) do { execute(a); count(a); } while(0);
else something_else();
```

which is correct, but:

```
if( something ) { execute(a); cout(a); };
else something_else();
```

would not be correct (the superfluous ";").

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cond)
   do_something(exp);
else 
   do_something_else(exp);
```

would not be valid C.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this: You can use break to get out of the while loop.

Comment: -1: What?  This is not the reason.

Comment: It is not the reason, but it is a reason.